# How to convert multiple lines string to dict in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I set a fact in Ansible using environment variables with `query('env', 'VARIABLE')`

My `VARIABLE` is multiline string (in YAML format):

```
device: eth0
bootproto: static
address: 192.168.x.x
netmask: 255.255.255.0 
gateway: 192.168.x.x
```

When I print the `VARIABLE` with Ansible, I get it as a single string with `\n` between lines

```
"msg": ["device: eth0\nbootproto: static\naddress: 
        192.168.x.x\nnetmask: 255.255.255.0\ngateway: 192.168.x.x"]
```

Is there a convenient way to convert it into dict? I need to use it later in my task, to load the parameters when configuring a machine's NIC.

I have tried to use the Jinja2 filter `- debug: msg="{{ network_settings | from_yaml }}"` with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an important note in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup.html#query):

> The difference between `lookup` and `query` is largely that **`query` will always return a list**.

So:

- either replace `query('env', 'VARIABLE')` with `lookup('env', 'VARIABLE')`:

  ```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('env', 'VARIABLE') | from_yaml }}"
  ```
- or process the list accordingly (the contents will be in the first-and-only element):

  ```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ query('env', 'VARIABLE') | first | from_yaml }}"
  ```